# Firefox is extremely slow over VNC

Tags: firefox, vnc

I'm using a mini PC (8GB RAM, 128GB SSD, Intel Celeron J4125I) with Xubuntu 20.04. It runs well with good performance. I've installed Vino to access the server remotely with a VNC client (Windows) and the performance is good.

My only issue occurs when using Firefox and other web browsers. Any web browser is very slow and impossible to use. Other apps, i.e. LiberOffice Calc, video player, etc. work fine via VNC.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the browser also slow while browsing simple text pages (no ads, videos, music, or pictures)?